# Node express docker-compose not running correctly the first time

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

The first time i run `docker-compose up` it gives and error because it cannot find the `app/index.js` (which shouldn't be existing anyway) file in the container. This is the time when the `dist` folder gets created. After stopping the container and running it again, this time it points to the correct file and everything works fine. I cannot understand why it points to the wrong first time. Normally the entrypoint of the file should be `app/dist/server.js` not `app/index.js`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
    container_name: backend-service
    image: backend-service
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
      - PORT=8095
    ports:
      - '8095:8095'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: yarn dev
```

Dockerfile (i used the ENTRYPOINT for testing. ignore the `CMD` as i want to run the `yarn dev` command from the `docker-compose.yml` file)

```
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine as base
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
WORKDIR /app
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine
# ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
EXPOSE 8095
CMD ["dist/server.js"]
```

my build script from package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/server.js\""
}
```

The error I get the first time

```
backend-service  | 6:38:44 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode...
backend-service  | [0]
backend-service  | [1] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
backend-service  | [1]   throw err;
backend-service  | [1]   ^
backend-service  | [1]
backend-service  | [1] Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
backend-service  | [1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
backend-service  | [1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
backend-service  | [1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
backend-service  | [1]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
backend-service  | [1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
backend-service  | [1]   requireStack: []
backend-service  | [1] }
backend-service  | [1]
backend-service  |
backend-service  | [1] Node.js v18.16.0
backend-service  |
backend-service  | [0]
backend-service  | [0] 6:38:48 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
backend-service  | [1]
backend-service  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
backend-service  | [1]   throw err;
backend-service  | [1]   ^
backend-service  | [1]
backend-service  | [1] Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
backend-service  | [1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
backend-service  | [1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
backend-service  | [1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
backend-service  | [1]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
backend-service  | [1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
backend-service  | [1]   requireStack: []
backend-service  | [1] }
backend-service  | [1]
backend-service  | [1] Node.js v18.16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dockerfile has [multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) . It should be like below. You don't need multistage build. Also, you mentioned workdir after copy. Either you should move workdir above copy. OR you should mention absolute path in copy.

```
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine as base
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app
RUN yarn build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8095
CMD ["dist/server.js"]
```

Comment: tried this way, but still the same issue. does not work the first time but works the second time

Comment: just found the reason why its pointing to `index.js` is because that is what is set in `package.json` file. if i change it to `"main": "dist/server.js",`, it still gives that error, but runs again automatically and the app starts working fine without having to docker compose again. so far this is the best i could find

Comment: Great. Mostly looks like path issue.